# Complex object comparison in C# without using recursive calls

Tags: c#, object, compare

I have ready many codes related to Object Comparison in C# but they use recursive calls, so my lead wants me to create a code without using recursive calls so that it doesn't fall in infinite loop.
I can't understand how recursive call can be evaded if there is an object array type inside object array type. Even when comparing Property and Field values.
Please help me out here.

Thanks

Comment: I would think the correct person to ask would be the lead. Do they know something you don’t? Is there some specific case that makes this possible?

Comment: The critical part to avoid endless recursion when traversing a graph is to keep track of which nodes you already have visited. You might use e.g. a HashSet for this that is passed through all the methods,

Comment: Changing an implementation from recursion to iteration will not fix an infinite loop (if it has any), that needs other measures (such as tracking the visited nodes). However: It is _always_ possible to change a recursive algorithm into an iterative one. You "just" need to use a Stack object instead of the runtime stack.